# Compare and Add to Wish List buttons have Disappeared from Website?

Tags: php, css, opencart, opencart2.x

Can someone help me please?

Was doing a bit of work trying to move these buttons but they have gone completely!

Here is a link to the website.

http://jmoncrieff.co.uk/Ceiling-Lights-Pendants-Semi-Flush-Chandeliers/Pendant-Lights-Kitchen-Pendants-/tone-pendant-in-a-variety-of-shades

Comment: The buttons are still there, at the top of the right hand column - however it seems the content text has been removed, or image for the button has been taken out of the css

Comment: Thanks for helping. How can I fix this?

Comment: It **looks** as if you have lost the css settings for .fa, .fa-exchange and .fa-heart. Go and have a look in your backed up copies and see what you have for those, add them back in.

Comment: Can't seem to find it anywhere in my restore files either. Just checked all the ones which were available. You any idea what has happened? Thank you for taking the time out to help me